# clojure.core.match on nested map

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching, clojure-core.match

in clojure.core.match , this example works well in nested map

```
(match [{:a {:b :c}}]
  [{:a {:b nested-arg}}] nested-arg)
```

but when change the `key` to a `vector` it will raise error.

```
(m/match x
  {:a {[:b :c]  1}}
  :found
  )
```

Isn't that `[:b :c]` is a valid key in clojure map ? Or it just won't work in `clojure.core.match` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[:b :c]` is of course a valid key. This is a bug and it was already reported, see [opened issue](https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/MATCH-107).

And it seems you can't also match map with numbers as keys:

```
(match/match [{:a 4}]
             [{:a _}] :found)
         
=> :found

(match/match [{2 4}]
             [{2 _}] :found)
         
Unexpected error (ClassCastException) macroexpanding match/match at ....
class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.Named (java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; clojure.lang.Named is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```